# Dica de livro para quem parou no tempo

Tags: php, c#, aplicação-web

Olá,

Programei até meados de 2012, parei nessa época e pretendo voltar meus estudos, mas muita coisa mudou. Minha principal área foi a web, utilizava php 5.3 , html 4 , css 2 e javascript com jQuery.

Chegou bastante tecnologia nova, minha principal loja para comprar livros era a linuxmall que infelizmente fechou.

Pretendo continuar na área web, mas dessa vez quero aproximar um pouco das ferramentas microsoft.

Já iniciei meus estudos em cakephp e em c#.

Abordagem atual:

Lendo a biblioteca oficial do cakephp e procurando melhorar quando possível em javascript. Acredito que o php que conheço seja o suficiente por enquanto.

Comecei a seguir [esse tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfvOpw8k80Wqj1a66Qsjh8jj4hlkzKSjA) mas parece que a organização em camadas que ele utiliza já esta desatualizada (BLL, DAL, GUI), conheço o MVC...

Bom se puderem recomendar alguma literatura que irá acelerar meus estudos em web e c# desktop ou melhor ainda voltado para web eu agradeceria, pois devido a quantidade de informação estou tendo muita procrastinação ao buscar as informações. Diria que estou meio impactado com tantas novidades desde quando parei na área.

Obrigado!

Comment: A pergunta vai acabar sendo fechada por ser baseada em opiniões, mas vou deixar minha contribuição pra você antes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbA_JZJtKaY

Comment: Olá Leatar, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Você pode encontrar algumas dessas informações nas próprias descrições das tags, clique sobre elas para dar uma olhada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o [Maicon](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4087/maicon-carraro) [disse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71668/dica-de-livro-para-quem-parou-no-tempo#comment146893_71668), a pergunta vai acabar por ser fechada por ser baseada em opiniões, porém também vou deixar algumas coisas que podem vir a ser úteis para ti.

---

Se o Inglês não for problema para ti recomendo-te os seguintes canais do YouTube:

- [DevTips](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyIe-61Y8C4_o-zZCtO4ETQ) - Web Development focado em Front-end.
- [PHPAcademy](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpOIUW62tnJTtpWFABxWZ8g) - Web Development focado em Back-end.
- [Derek Banas](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwRXb5dUK4cvsHbx-rGzSgw) - App Development porém se não me engano ensina um pouco de C#
- [Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYbK_tjZ2OrIZFBvU6CCMiA) - Game Development também ensina C#.

Se quiseres ler livros recomendo visitares [este site](https://it-ebooks.info/) onde encontras bastantes livros de programação atualizados.

---

Caso o Inglês seja um problema eu não te posso ajudar muito, o que te posso indicar é procurares alguns livros ou canais no YouTube pois realmente eu conheço muito poucos e maior parte deles já não existem ou estão desatualizados.

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações, não entendo muito as regras do stackoverflow... Se tiver outras dicas mesmo em inglês eu agradeço.

Comment: @Leatar Esqueci-me de referir que a existência de uma [wiki](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) para a tag php, dá uma olhada e vê se encontras algo que te ajude também.